# How to show query from all the tables(same structure) and order all by data

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know how I can select query from more than 1 table to show and order then all by the data and limit then to a number(if I put LIMIT 5, to show only the most recently add by data 5 query from all the tables not the last recently add 5 of one of the tables, cause I want make like a newsbar)
I have 5 tables(categories) with the same structure (id, title, descriere, poza, data) and I want to show only the last 5 of them all.

```
//create connection to mysql
$db_conx_index = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$db_conx_index->set_charset('utf8');// pentru diacritice
if(!$db_conx_index){
 die("Connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
$catArray = array("istorie", "lifestyle", "sciente", "travel", "nature");    
$slider = '';
foreach($catArray as $k=>$v)
{    
    $sql = "SELECT id, titlu, data, linknews, poza FROM ".$v."  WHERE approved='1' ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 5";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx_index, $sql);   
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $titlu = $row["titlu"];
        $linknews = $row["linknews"];
        $poza = $row["poza"];
        $slider .= '<a href="/'.$linknews.'"><img src="/images/'.$poza.'-600x.jpg" alt="'.$titlu.'"></a>';
    } 
}
?>  
     <?php echo $slider;?> 
    <?php mysqli_close($db_conx_index);?>
```

but the code show me the last 5 query for every one tables and order by each other then comes the secont tables.. and want to order without take in calculation the first table....

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: If I am not wrong you want to fire a single query and get data from all 5 tables instead of  5 query ?

Comment: Database structure would be truely helpful. And you may want to have a look at the UNION statement in SQL.

Comment: no, I want to make like a Sidernews, so I wanna to take only the last 5 querry add sort by table data(which has the data form). So how i can make UNION? which is the code?

Comment: Stefan please give us examples, you are not explaining you self well!

Comment: So I have 5 tables (lifestyle, istorie, natura, travel, science) all with the some structure (id, title, poza, data, approved, descriere) and I want to select and show only 5 queries from all the tables, which by order by DATA,  the most recently add,  but now show me 5 queries for every tables that means 25 query without order by time, so i want to show only 5 queries in total, and i understood i can use UNION

Answer (score 0):

Forget the `foreach` loop.

```
"SELECT id, titlu, data, linknews, poza FROM istorie, lifestyle, sciente, travel, nature  WHERE approved='1' ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 5"
```